# Tkinter | Listbox | I can't get curselection to work

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

***`THIS PROBLEM IS RESOLVED!!!`***

**Hi!** I'm kinda confused – Because of fun, I've decided to make a quick and dirty program to make my life a bit easier.
Turns out that I'm apparently not that good with Tkinter.
Since I'm also not good at explaining things, I'll let you look at the code instead of trying to describe it.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I want to print all the options a user selects in the listbox to the console. In the long run, I want to write them to an Excel file, but that is going to be a different story. You might see me back on here at that point.  :D

Please keep in mind:

- I'm currently in the process of teaching myself how python works. (All through YouTube videos)
- I do **not** have a professional background/any prior knowledge about coding or similar.
- All comments within the code are written in German.
- All Names and texts have been changed to ensure privacy.

(I have marked where my current problem is with a comment)

This is the mess I'm talking about:

```
#######################################################
#-----------------Name of Program-----------------#
#######################################################
#---------------------My Name---------------------#
#######################################################


#Notwendige resourcen importieren
from tkinter import *


#Fenster erstellen & definieren
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x300")
win.title("Changed name")



#Optionmenu liste
OPTIONS = [
"Name1",
"Name2",
"Name3"
]


#Auswahl bzw. User-Input annehmen & verarbeiten
auswahl1 = StringVar(win)
auswahl1.set(OPTIONS[1])


#OptionMenu erstellen
option1 = OptionMenu(win, auswahl1, *OPTIONS)
option1.place(x=215, y=120)



#frame & scrollbar wegen tkinter scrollbar
my_frame = Frame(win)
my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient=VERTICAL)





##############################################
#-----------------Funktionen-----------------#
##############################################



#Funktion um die "nächste Seite" zu erstellen.
def nextpage1():


    # Variablen aus einer Funktion, für alle anderen Funktionen verfügbar/erreichbar machen.
    global Knopf2
    global my_listbox


    # 1. Knopf (Startknopf) Zerstören/Löschen
    Knopf1.destroy()


    # my_Listbox erstellen
    my_listbox = Listbox(my_frame,  width=50, height=60, selectmode="multiple", font=("Helvetica", 13), justify=CENTER, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)


    #Scrollbar definieren
    my_scrollbar.config(command=my_listbox.yview)
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)


    #my_frame auf Bildschirm "packen"
    my_frame.pack()


    #my_listbox auf Bildschirm "packen"
    my_listbox.pack(padx=5, pady=15)


    #2. Knopf erstellen & definieren
    Knopf2 = Button(win, text="Next2", command=buttonpress2)
    Knopf2.place(x=440, y=10)


    #liste für my_listbox
    a_list = ["Option1.",
              "Option2.",
              "Option3.",
              "Option4.",
              "Option5.",
              "Option6.",
              "Option7.",
              "Option8.",
              "Option9.",
              "Option10.",
              "Option11.",
              "Option12.",
              "Option13.",
              "Option14.",
              "Option15.",
              "Option16"
              ]


    #Liste (a_list) in my_Listbox schreiben/einfügen
    for item in a_list:
        my_listbox.insert(END, item)


############################################################################################
#Funktion um my_listbox auszulesen (THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK!!)
def printlist():
    my_frame.destroy()
    print(my_listbox.curselection())
    # global listauswahl
    # listauswahl = ""
    # my_listbox.get(listauswahl)



#Funktion um 3. Seite zu erstellen
def nextpage2():
    Knopf2.destroy()
    my_listbox.destroy()
    Knopf3 = Button(win, text="Next3", command=buttonpress3)
    Knopf3.place(x=440, y=10)



#Funtion für 1. Knopf
def buttonpress1():
    option1.destroy()
    print(auswahl1.get())    
    textvar.set("text1")
    nextpage1()



#Funtion für 2. Knopf
def buttonpress2():
    print("")     
    nextpage2()
    textvar.set("text2")
    printlist()



#Funtion für 3. Knopf
def buttonpress3():
    option1.destroy()
    print(auswahl1.get())     
    textvar.set("text3")



#####################################################
#-----------------End of Funktionen-----------------#
#####################################################





#Label Start-Text
textvar = StringVar()
textvar.set("text0")



#Label erstellen & definieren
Label(textvariable=textvar, bg="lightblue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
Label(text="").pack()



#1. Knopf für start definieren
Knopf1 = Button(win, text="Next1", command=buttonpress1)
Knopf1.place(x=440, y=10)


mainloop()
```

This is the Error it outputs:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 146, in buttonpress2
    printlist()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 116, in printlist
    print(my_listbox.curselection())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3175, in curselection
    return self._getints(self.tk.call(self._w, 'curselection')) or ()
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!listbox"
```

I don't know if that's too much to ask or not. I just see other people get help on here all the time, so I thought I'd give it a try!

Please let me know if you can see anything else wrong with my code. (You'll probably find a lot.)

**Thanks & Greetings from Switzerland.**

Comment: Since `my_listbox` is a child of `my_frame`, it is also destroyed when `my_frame` is destroyed.

Comment: @acw1668 If I take the my_frame.destroy() out, it outputs the same error as originally stated.

Comment: `my_listbox` is destroyed (after calling `nextpage2()`) before calling `printlist()` inside `buttonpress2()`.

Comment: @acw1668 You were indeed right with both of your comments. Thanks a lot! That fixed it!